# PhpStorm Formatter failed to format the document

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm

Similar questions have been asked, but what makes mine different is that I seem to have the configuration correct. Here is my configuration (my name has been redacted, for privacy reasons).

[image]

What I know is that my PhpStorm IDE has not been activated yet; is that required or is my configuration incorrect, despite the folder and file being at these places?

Comment: Are you trying to use PhpStorm from within VSCode to format your files? Which means: calling PhpStorm as a command-line app: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/command-line-formatter.html If that's "YES" then I'm pretty sure that PhpStorm has to have some license active or be in the evaluation period. As per docs the Code Style settings file can be located anywhere as it can be passed as an argument in the command line (`-s` param).

Comment: 1) Check what command VSCode is trying to execute here, then open your OS console and try to run it there -- will you see any errors in the output? 2) In either case -- check the `idea.log` file -- the IDE will write it there. Normally it will be here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory

Comment: I'm using the PHPStorm extension in VSCode, which executes a command in the PHPStorm /bin folder. If it requires the IDE to be licensed, that's a bit of an issue. I'll check the log and check back here shortly.

Comment: Yeah okay, seems it requires a valid license. Could you provide that as an answer, so I can set it as being the solution to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to [use PhpStorm from within VSCode to format your files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=animus-coop.vscode-phpstorm-formatter). Which means: [calling PhpStorm as a command-line app.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/command-line-formatter.html)

**I'm pretty sure that PhpStorm has to have a valid active licence or be in the evaluation period** (so it has be "activated" in some way). I remember seeing tickets with similar issue when  using PhpStorm for code inspections in Continuous Integration tools.

In any case:

1. Check what command VSCode is trying to execute here, then open your OS console and try to run it there -- will you see any errors/warnings in the output?
2. If you do not see any such messages there then check the `idea.log` file -- the IDE will write everything there for sure.

   On Windows it would *normally* be in the `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm2022.2\log` folder (for the current 2022.2 version). Other OS / cusom location -- check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory

---

> ...or is my configuration incorrect, despite the folder and file being at these places?

As per docs the Code Style settings file can be located anywhere: it can be in the [default place](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory) as well as any other as it can be passed [as an argument in the command line](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/command-line-formatter.html#options) (`-s` parameter). So keeping the file with Code Style settings in the VSCode extension folder is OK as long as that parameter is used.